# VB2010 & MSACCESS | Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i'm making a login form and every time i try to login(whether with a correct or not user) it gives me the same error.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here's the code:

```
Public Class login
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Fausto\Documents\GitHub\CRE\cre.accdb;")
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT USERID FROM USERS WHERE USERID=@p_userid AND PASSWORD=@p_passw;"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Private Sub login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'I figured how to make comments in VB! Yeey
        'Temporarely redirecting to menuForm
        With cmd
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("p_userid", username.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("p_passw", password.Text)
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim usr As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
            If Not (IsDBNull(usr)) AndAlso usr = username.Text Then
                Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            Else
                Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not connect to DB hahahaha" & Environment.NewLine & "Error message: " & ex.Message)
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            Me.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub closeBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles closeBtn.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        credits.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm using Visual Basic Express and Microsoft Access 2010,
Thanks :D

Comment: Comment out the `Catch` statement so you can see the line the error actually happens on.

Comment: i've commented out its still gives me the same error.

Comment: I know it will still give the error - however, it should now break on what line exactly the exception is raised. So... what line is it?

Comment: @ChrisRolliston it breaks at:
 Dim usr As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

I saw several issues, but I think the one addressed in the question is here:

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Fausto\Documents\GitHub\CRE\cre.accdb;")
Dim sql As String = "SELECT USERID FROM USERS WHERE USERID=@p_userid AND PASSWORD=@p_passw;"
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
```

The problem is that those variables are class-level, initialized prior to the class constructor, and the order in which the variables are initialized is not guaranteed. What is happening is that, at the point when the `New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)` code executes, the `conn` variable is not guaranteed to have initialized.

This omission will fly under the radar, all the way until you try to execute a command, here:

```
Dim usr As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
```

Aside from needing parentheses for the function call, it's not unil this point that the `OleDbCommand` object finally tries to use the connection supplied earlier and discovers that there's `Nothing` there.

While I have your attention, I also need to point out that you're using the wrong parameter notation for OleDb (you need to use `?` placeholders instead of `@NameParameters`). Also, this is a horrible way to handle authentication. *NEVER* store a password in plain text like that.

Comment: what do you suggest then?

I'm storing a password in a plain text because its for school.

Comment: Before a password is stored, it should have a per-user salt added to it, and the salted password should then be run through a cryptographically secure one-way hashing algorithm. If this is for school, that's fine, but you should have a general awareness of the right way.

Comment: Now say that in english, i dont understand much of VB its my first big project.